# Dibujar BufferedImage con el metodo paint

Tags: java, jframe, bufferedimage

Estoy intentando mostrar un `BufferedImage` en un frame, (la imagen la acabé de modificar por sus valores RGB). El método `paint` no reconoce la imagen cuando la escribo, así que se la paso como parámetro. El problema es como llamar el método y pasarle la imagen como parámetro

Aquí creo la imagen (dentro del main, ya tiene el frame hecho y todo).

```
fondo = new BufferedImage(800,800,BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_RGB);
```

Aquí tengo el método paint sobreescrito

```
public static void paint (Graphics g, Image fondo){       
  g.drawImage(fondo, 50, 50, null);
}
```

Mi problema es como llamar el metodo con esa imagen como parámetro, o como insertar esa imagen al frame

Answer (score 0):

Una forma muy simple de hacer el mismo trabajo seria con el siguiente algoritmo, que debes colocar después del constructor del JFrame

```
@Override
public void paint(Graphics g) {
    Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D) g;
    ImageIcon imagen = new ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("recursos/abstracto4.jpg"));
    System.out.println("imagen: "+imagen.getIconWidth()+" "+imagen.getIconHeight());
    g2d.drawImage(imagen.getImage(), 0, 0,getWidth(),getHeight(), null);
}
```

Comment: Hola,ya implementé el método y no me da errores. Pero al compilar no hace nada, coloqué algunos System.out para verificar que entraba al bloque de código y no aparece nada en pantalla. ¿Sabes qué puede ser?

Comment: recuerda que la imagen debe estar dentro de tu proyecto. Yo lo coloque en el paquete base/recursos.....para que asi puedas desplegar la imagen. El algoritmo funciona correctamente. Si persiste la dificultad no dudes en escribir.